# Google Calendar PHP retrieve events from multiple calendars

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was following a tutorial on using the Google Calendar API with the ZEND Framework(http://maestric.com/doc/php/google_calendar_api). I am able to retrieve events from my default calendar by setting the calendar ID: `$query->setUser('IDGoesHere');`. The problem is I'm not sure how to grab events from all of the calendars I am subscribed to. Is there a way to achieve this or is it not even possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the PHP:

```
$path = 'ZendGdata/library';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;

try
{
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user,$pass,$service);          
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo "Could not connect to calendar.";
die();
}

$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
$query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();

$query->setUser('usernameHere');
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setSingleEvents(true);
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('ascending');
$query->setMaxResults(20);

$event_list = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
```

Grab the events and display them:
    `foreach ($event_list as $event)
    {
    echo $event->title ';
    echo $event->where[0];
    echo $event->content ;
    }`

Comment: Show us your code for how you are getting calendar data now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setUser` to the user id of the secondary calendar.

Comment: I know that I can change `setUser` to grab events from other calendars I am subscribed too. I am trying to grab events from both users and display them both at the same time.

Comment: You'll have to make separate requests for each calendar. They are separate resources.